# Java + Appium + iOS [mobile] : How to fix error "Error: spawn ios_webkit_debug_proxy ENOENT"?

Tags: java, appium, ios, mobile-automation

I am trying to automate web app on iPhone using Mac. Executing webkit debug proxy for automation on iOS platform.
I am facing below issue:

```
RUNNING: ios_webkit_debug_proxy 
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ios_webkit_debug_proxy ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:478:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:392:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:432:11)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:1003:3
```

Q - How to fix error "Error: spawn ios_webkit_debug_proxy ENOENT" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Comment: Good to see response Shailendra - I have tried few solutions and other more on windows environment :(

Comment: Can you please check if developer option on you ios are enabled and automation is turned on in iphone settings?